# humb in seekbar laying down to seekbar

Tags: android, layout, android-seekbar

[image]

here i have problem that  in seekbar thumb is not on seekbar, how to solve this problem

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playbutton"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekdot" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:max="300"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:progress="0"

       />
```

while styled progressxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/SecondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_empty"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
   android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_full"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set minHeight and maxHeight same as the height of seekbar. eg

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/playbutton"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekdot" 
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:max="300"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:progress="0"
   android:minHeight="11dip"
    android:maxHeight="11dip"
       />
```